# Problem with random package code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have the following simple "random walk" code:

```
import random

def random_walk(n):
    """Return coordinates after 'n' block random walk."""
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(['N', 'S', 'E', 'W'])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == 'S':
            y == y - 1
        elif step == 'W':
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x - 1
        return (x,y)

for i in range(25):
    walk = random_walk(10)
    print(walk, "Distance from home = ", abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))
```

**I have two problems**:

(A) When I run this in Visual Studio Code it tells me that variable i is
    not used. It gets "underlined" giving me the following error:

```
[pylint] Unused variable 'i' [W0612] (10,6)
[pylint] Unused variable 'i' [W0101] (22,3)
```

Note that Sublime and Jupyter have no problem running it.

(B) For some reason I never am able to move more than one step in x
    direction and one in y direction. As a result my distance from home
    is always 0,1 or   But the code above clearly states that we walk
    for n blocks and not
        just 0, 1, or 2 blocks.

```
(0, 1) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(0, 1) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(0, 0) Distance from home = 0
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(0, 0) Distance from home = 0
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(0, 0) Distance from home = 0
(0, 1) Distance from home = 1
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(0, 0) Distance from home = 0
(1, 0) Distance from home = 1
(0, 0) Distance from home = 0
(0, 0) Distance from home = 0
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The "Unused variable" message is not an error, it's a warning. And it is telling you true: you set `i` in the head of the `for` statement, but you don't use the value of `i` anywhere. If you don't need the value of `i` then you can ignore the warning.

Comment: VSCode also "has no problems running it". It simply warns you that you defined a variable `i` and never used it (which is true). The Python convention is to use `_` in these cases, ie `for _ in range(n)`.

Comment: Visual Studio telling you that a variable is not used, does not mean that it is unable to run it. So there is not really a difference to Sublime or Jupyter in that regard, the latter just don't tell you about the unused variable.

Comment: You have a typo here: `y == y - 1` should be `y = y - 1`

Comment: Because of your indentation, `return (x,y)` is inside of your `for` loop. So your function returns after the first iteration every time. You want it *after* your `for` loop completes. Outdent it. Python uses indentation to determine block structure.

Comment: @lurker thank you very much! one question: why does Jupyter have no problem with the unused i?

Comment: Jupyter, by default, evidently doesn't think it's important enough to warn you that you aren't using it. They may have an option you can set to get such warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Unused variable" message is not an error, it's a warning. It is telling you true: you set `i` in the head of the for statement, but you don't use the value of `i` anywhere. If you don't need the value of `i` then you can ignore the warning. Jupyter, by default, evidently doesn't think it's important enough to warn you that you aren't using it (or it indicated a warning that you missed). They may have an option you can set to get such warnings.

Since you aren't using `i`, you can use `_` to avoid the warning (`_` takes the place of a variable name that you aren't using):

```
for _ in range(n):
```

And, in your main program:

```
for _ in range(25):
```

You have a typo: `y == y - 1` should be `y = y - 1`

Because of your indentation, `return (x,y)` is inside of your for loop. So your function returns after the first iteration every time. You want it after your for loop completes. Outdent it. Python uses indentation to determine block structure.

```
for i in range(n):
    ...

    else:
        x = x - 1

return (x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new in Python and your answers and comments help a lot.

Comment: @Marion no worries. I added a little more to indicate how you can get rid of the warning.